# How to integrate Google map with my app in Android2.1?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout

I am writing an application in android 2.1. I just want to implement Google map for my app. I found this link  [Google Map](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android). Its good.

But I found out, For google map I have to create a project with a Google API version. Which is Along with Android2.2. But my application is in Android2.1. So How I can integrate Google map with 2.1.
What I am thinking I have to create a new project with Google API2.2 version. Then I have to move all my code from current project to that. Am I wrong?
If I am right, Then will this run on 2.1? I it always run for 2.2 and above only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select Google APIs for 2.1 also. Select Google APIS with 2.0.1 and then follow the [link](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android)

as mentioned by you.

Comment: So I have to create new project. No way to integrate Google Map in the old one? And what about Android 1.6?
Dose it mean there I have to take my code in my new project based on Google API2.1?

Comment: Yes there is, you can change the version(Target) of your old project. Just right click on the project, go to properties, and then select Android from the left panel , and finally change the version(target) for your project and then apply..

Comment: Can you please tell will this require any additional thing on Device?

Comment: Nothing special. But you must have some internet plan on your device and must have taken the internet permission in manifest file .

Answer (score 0):

One thing is sure that for whole application you should include only one api version that can

be Google android 2.1 or google android 2.2, i have jst checked it you can use any one api of

the mentioned above two.. and you will get d same result, without changing your code.....